# Ditaa diagrams in TeX (LaTeX) document

Tags: graphics, diagrams, tools, embedding

I would like to make Diagrams in AsciiArt style.

I've found [Ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/) tool very usefull.
I was happy to find, there is [Eps output addoon for it](http://ditaa-addons.sourceforge.net/).

What the easiest, but clear and elegant way (following KISS principle) do you suggest to

- embed ditaa diagrams into Tex (LaTeX) documents?

Makefile with eps->pdf conversion and than including such pdf. Keep asciiart diagrams separated or integrate it somehow with Tex/LaTex (for asciidoc, I've found it easy).

I know it's more poweruser question, but related:

- Unfortunatelly, I can figure out how to make it working with newest ditaa 0.9 (it's distributed with ditaa 0.6b)

I am new to group, so please forgive (kindly remind, I can delete it) if question is not appropriate.

I am Linux programmer, so command line, make, sed, awk and other tool can be combined.

Comment: Tikz can do a lot of great diagrams, too, natively!

Comment: Simplest way (KISS) include the image as .png or .jpg with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: So, I would like to {\includegraphics}. But to have ditaa diagram embedded in TeX document, so while compiling it, picture is vectorized externally and resulting vector (DitaaEps) Eps version is included.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in merely adding ascii-art diagrams to your document, you can dump the ascii-art content in the verbatim environment:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
​\begin{document}% Taken from http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/
\begin{verbatim}
    +--------+   +-------+    +-------+
    |        | --+ ditaa +--> |       |
    |  Text  |   +-------+    |diagram|
    |Document|   |!magic!|    |       |
    |     {d}|   |       |    |       |
    +---+----+   +-------+    +-------+
        :                         ^
        |       Lots of work      |
        +-------------------------+
​\end{verbatim}
\end{document}​​​​​​
```

The verbatim environment typesets its contents as-is using the `\ttfamily` font, keeping the alignment (whitespace).

[image: Example of ditaa ascii-art code]

If you're interested in a converted graphic/image (a *`ditaa`-processed* version of your ascii-art), then importing a PNG (or JPG/BMP) from your ditaa outpout would be easiest. This, however, comes with a loss of quality in the output. If the EPS add-on is readily available, then using it to produce EPS images (or even converted to PDF) would achieve the highest quality. Here's a graphic from the website illustrating the difference in quality when using [rasterized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) vs [vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) graphics:

[image: Difference in rasterized and vector graphics in ditaa output]

Finally, [`TikZ/PGF`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [`PStricks`](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) both provide a bounty of native drawing capabilities within (La)TeX. The [`TikZ/PGF` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) is filled with examples, as is many of the [package documentations associated with `PStricks`](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=packages). They each come with their own set of macros/commands that allow for drawing diagrams similar to those done by `ditaa`.

The advantage of using native packages as opposed to some external application (like `ditaa`) is that it provides the capability to alter an "image" within your (La)TeX code rather than using an external application as a stepping stone. Moreover, with (La)TeX being platform independent, such advantages of native programming add even more value.

Comment: I would like to use vector version of DitaaEps, but with Ditaa 0.9.

Answer (score 3):

If you are an `emacs` user, you may consider using `org-mode` extension: [http://orgmode.org/](http://orgmode.org)

I have been using `org-mode` for some to prepare documents and presentations in LaTeX/Beamer.  You can use `org-mode` to generate both LaTeX files and html files.

To incorporate code from other languages (e.g. Python, Ruby, C++, ditaa, tikz, etc.), you will need to use the `babel` functionality: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/
In particular, [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#sec-5_4), is an `org-mode` ditaa example from the `babel` extension.

Comment: I am Vim user - about org-mode, I've read on webpage. But thanks :).

Comment: There is, from time to time, some talk on the `org-mode` mailing list about making a Vim clone.  I believe some users have started such a project, for example the [VimOrganizer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3342), just FYI.

Comment: Thanks man. :). Even it's out of question , cause it doesn not solve vector rendering problem, it's interesting as editor tool :).

Comment: @cm2, I know this is an old post now, but maybe you can help.
I am using org-mode, with ditaa in a src block. My problem is that when I save all trailing white space is removed. Normally that is nice, but the ditaa does not render correctly without that space on the end. Any ideas?

Comment: @JonathanPeel Sorry, my use of orgmode has waxed and waned over the years, so a solution doesn't come to mind.  You might get some traction on https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/ which seems to be fairly active.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted exactly the feature asked by this question.
I want to embed a ditaa asciiart in my latex files and at the same time embed an image rendered by ditaa by only doing pdflatex once.

Since I realized that there is no such a thing by this post, I have created it and am sharing it here.
https://gist.github.com/dakusui/160dba81fb7dc53d24b3596ef21bd979

IMPORTANT: You need to compile it with --enable-write18 option.
IMPORTANT: You need to install `ditaa` command beforehand.
Please try this and I hope you can enjoy it.

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\ImageResourcePath{./resources/graphics/}
\graphicspath{ {\ImageResourcePath} }

\newenvironment{ditaa}[2]
{
  \def\ditaacaption{#1}
  \def\ditaastem{#2}
  \def\ditaadir{\ImageResourcePath/ditaa2}
  \def\ditaafile{\ditaadir/\ditaastem.ditaa}
  \VerbatimOut{\ditaafile}}
{\endVerbatimOut
  \immediate\write18{ditaa "\ditaafile" "\ditaadir/\ditaastem.png"}
  \begin{figure}
      \caption{\ditaacaption}
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{ditaa2/\ditaastem}
  \end{figure}
}
%--------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    This is a ditaa diagramm example.
    \begin{ditaa}{ditaa caption example}{ditaaexample}
      +--------+   +-------+    +-------+
      |        | --+ ditaa +--> |       |
      |  Text  |   +-------+    |diagram|
      |Document|   |!magic!|    |       |
      |     {d}|   |       |    |       |
      +---+----+   +-------+    +-------+
          :                         ^
          |       Lots of work      |
          +-------------------------+
    \end{ditaa}
    Enjoy!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.